# Getting the src of an img and storing it into a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the `img` is clicked I want to use the function `handleImgCLick` to get an ID from the img src and store it in a variable and use it outside the `handleImgCLick` function but I'm getting undefined.

Declared the var `clickedImgID` outside the `handleImgCLick` function trying to access it outside.

```
let clickedImgID;
```

The `handleImgCLick` function extracts the ID of the `src` which is a regluar link which the I get from an `onClick`

```
  const handleImgCLick = (e) => {
    function getID(url) {
      url = url.split(/(vi\/|v%3D|v=|\/v\/|ujd\.be\/|\/ss\/)/);
      return undefined !== url[2] ? url[2].split(/[^0-9a-z_\-]/i)[0] : url[0];
    }
//****Trying to store the value from the function and store it in clickedImgID which is declared outside the function****
  
  clickedImgID = getID(e.target.src)
  };
```

The img below when clicked triggers the function `handleImgCLick` to extract the an ID from the src

```
<img
          className="m-4 mx-auto hover:cursor-pointer "
          width="280"
          height="160"
          src={`${fetchData.videos[i].thumbnail}`}
          onClick={handleImgCLick}
        ></img>
```

I tried the method above and tried declaring `clickedImgID` as an array and pushed `getID(e.target.src)` into it but it only worked sometimes.

Comment: You haven't showed enough of your actual component code to be sure, but it looks like you're declaring `clickedImgID` as a variable in the top level of your component. If so it will be redeclared every render and lose its value. Use a `ref` or state variable. (`const clickedImgID = useRef();` and then `clickedImgID.current = getID(e.target.src)`)

Comment: Used a useState var and it worked, thank you.